# Peculiar instruction sequence generated from straightforward C "if" lack condition

Tags: c

I am trying to debug some simple C code under gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 for x86-64.  The code is built with `CFLAGS += -std=c99 -g -Wall -O0`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma pack(1)

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        FILE    *f = fopen ("the_file", "r"); /* error checking removed for clarity */

        struct {
                short   len;
                short   itm [4];
                char    nul;
        } f00f;

        int n = fread (&f00f, 1, sizeof f00f, f);

        if (f00f.nul   ||
            f00f.len != 0x900       ||      
            f00f.itm [0] != 0xf00f  ||      
            f00f.itm [1] != 0xf00f  ||
            f00f.itm [2] != 0xf00f  ||
            f00f.itm [3] != 0xf00f)
        {
                fprintf (stderr, "bitfile_hdr F00F data err:\n"
                    "\tNUL:  0x%x\n"
                    "\tlen:  0x%hx should be 0x900\n"
                    "\tf00f:  0x%hx\n"
                    "\tf00f:  0x%hx\n"
                    "\tf00f:  0x%hx\n"
                    "\tf00f:  0x%hx\n"
                    , f00f.nul, f00f.len,
                    f00f.itm[0], f00f.itm[1], f00f.itm[2], f00f.itm[3]
                    );
                return 1;
         }
         return  0;
}
```

The data matches what the test expects, and—weirdly—the error message displays the correct data:

```
$ ./bit_parse
bitfile_hdr F00F data err:
    NUL:  0x0
    len:  0x900 should be 0x900
    f00f:  0xf00f
    f00f:  0xf00f
    f00f:  0xf00f
    f00f:  0xf00f
```

Running it under `gdb` and examining the structure also shows correct data.

```
(gdb) p /x f00f
$1 = {len = 0x900, itm = {0xf00f, 0xf00f, 0xf00f, 0xf00f}, nul = 0x0}
```

Since that didn't make sense, I examined the instructions from inside `gdb` to reveal coding pathologies.  The instructions corresponding to the non-functioning `if` are:

```
   0x0000000000400736 <+210>:   movzwl -0x38(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040073a <+214>:   movswl %ax,%r8d
   0x000000000040073e <+218>:   movzwl -0x3a(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400742 <+222>:   movswl %ax,%edi
   0x0000000000400745 <+225>:   movzwl -0x3c(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400749 <+229>:   movswl %ax,%r9d
   0x000000000040074d <+233>:   movzwl -0x3e(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400751 <+237>:   movswl %ax,%r10d
   0x0000000000400755 <+241>:   movzwl -0x40(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400759 <+245>:   movswl %ax,%ecx
   0x000000000040075c <+248>:   movzbl -0x36(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400760 <+252>:   movsbl %al,%edx
   0x0000000000400763 <+255>:   mov    $0x4008d8,%esi
   0x0000000000400768 <+260>:   mov    0x2008d1(%rip),%rax  # 0x601040 <stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x000000000040076f <+267>:   mov    %r8d,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400774 <+272>:   mov    %edi,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400777 <+275>:   mov    %r10d,%r8d
   0x000000000040077a <+278>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040077d <+281>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400782 <+286>:   callq  0x400550 <fprintf@plt>
   0x0000000000400787 <+291>:   mov    $0x6,%eax
   0x000000000040078c <+296>:   add    $0x50,%rsp
   0x0000000000400790 <+300>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000400791 <+301>:   pop    %r12
   0x0000000000400793 <+303>:   pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400794 <+304>:   retq
```

It is really hard to see how this could implement a conditional.

Anyone see why this (mis)behaves as it does?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but wouldn't `fread (&f00f, 1, sizeof f00f, f);` make more sense that `fread (&f00f, sizeof f00f, 1, f);`? According to the documentation I have, this would ensure you do not read half a struct.

Comment: Does that assembly come immediately after the `fread` call?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I think the documentation for `fread` is not so useful.  I usually want to validate the number of bytes, not the number of items.  That's why I always "turn it around" to be able to report how short a short read was.

Comment: On an unrelated note please clean up your coding conventions

Comment: @aschepler:  Yes, logically it does.  In the unabridged code, there was a check that `fread` read enough bytes to fill the structure.  I took it out because a) it always works, and b) to simplify the question.

Comment: @SeriousBusiness:  What do you mean?  The code is completely cleanly coded.

Comment: @wallyk f00f is an awful name for a struct, or anything really. Whitespace usage isn't consistent either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably on your platform, `short` is 16-bit wide. Therefore no `short` can equal `0xf00f` and the condition `f00f.itm [0] != 0xf00f` is always true. The compiler optimized accordingly.

You may have meant `unsigned short` in the definition of `struct f00f`, but this is only one way to fix it, of course. You could also compare `f00f.itm [0]` to `(short)0xf00f`, but if you meant `f00f.itm[i]` to be compared to `0xf00f`, you definitely should have used `unsigned short` in the definition.

Comment: Short is 16 bits, but so is 0xf00f.

Comment: @wallyk `0xf00f` fits a 16-bit unsigned integer type, but it does not fit a 16-bit signed integer type.

Comment: In gcc `-Wextra` will warn about such comparisons: `warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]`

Comment: Yep.  That was the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`short val = 0xf00f;` assigns the value -4081 to val.

You get hit by integer promotion rules.

```
 f00f.itm [0] != 0xf00f
```

converts the short in `f00f.itm [0]` to an int, and that's -4081. 0xf00f as an int is 61455, and those two are not equal. Since the value is converted to an unsigned short when you print out the values (by using `%hx`), the issue isn't visible in the output.

Use unsigned values in your struct since you seem to treat the values as unsigned:

```
struct {
           unsigned short   len;
           unsigned short   itm [4];
           char    nul;
    } f00f;
```

This sample program might make you understand what's going on a bit better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *arga[])
{
    short x = 0xf00f;
    int y  =  0xf00f;

    printf("x = 0x%hx y = 0x%x\n", x, y);
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
    printf("x==y: %d\n", x == y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  I just validated it, but since Pascal answered first, he gets the credit.